Batch Inference for Llama to compute mean log-probabilities of tokens
I have a dataset of inputs, my goal is to first use them to generate some outputs and compute the mean log-probabilities of the generated tokens. I am stuck at the first step of trying to do the inference.
First of all, here is the model:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

# Replace this with the actual model path or identifier
model_name = "meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct"

# Load tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, use_fast=False)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    device_map="auto",  # Automatically map layers to available devices
    load_in_8bit=True,  # Enable 8-bit quantization
    offload_folder="./offload",  # Offload layers to this folder
    offload_state_dict=True  # Offload unused state_dict to CPU
)

Next, dataset and basic preprocessing:
from datasets import load_dataset

# Load the dataset
dataset = load_dataset("ai2-adapt-dev/flan_v2_converted")  # Replace with actual dataset path or identifier
def preprocess(example):
    """Preprocess dataset into input-output pairs"""
    return {
        "input_text": example['inputs'],
        "target_text": example['targets'],
    }

def tokenize_function(examples, tokenizer):
    """Tokenize input and output text"""
    model_inputs = tokenizer(
        examples["input_text"],
        max_length=512,
        truncation=True,
        padding="max_length",
    )
    labels = tokenizer(
        examples["target_text"],
        max_length=512,
        truncation=True,
        padding="max_length",
    )
    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs

train_dataset = dataset["train"].map(preprocess)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tokenize_function(x, tokenizer), batched=True)

Let's say I have a batch of dataset
train_dataset_subset = train_dataset[:10] # a dictionary of lists of 10
My goal is to do something like
# These are wrong codes....
input_ids = train_dataset_subset['input_ids']
generated_ids = model.generate(input_ids)
outputs = model(generated_ids)
logits = outputs.logits

# Calculate probabilities
log_probs = []
for i in range(1, generated_ids.size(1)):  # Skip the first token
    token_logits = logits[0, i - 1, :]  # Logits for the previous token
    token_id = generated_ids[0, i]  # Current token ID
    token_prob = F.log_softmax(token_logits, dim=-1)[token_id].item()
    log_probs.append(token_prob)

# Calculate total log probability and average probability
total_log_prob = sum(log_probs)
avg_log_prob = total_log_prob / len(log_probs)

print(f"Total log probability: {total_log_prob:.4f}")
print(f"Average log probability: {avg_log_prob:.4f}")

